# Concatenate on specific condition python

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, concatenation

- EDITED

I want to write an If loop with conditions on cooncatenating strings.
i.e. If cell A1 contains a specific format of text, then only do you concatenate, else leave as is.

example:
If bill number looks like: CM2/0000/, then concatenate this string with the date column (month - year), else leave the bill number as it is.

[Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMCdU.png)

Comment: Please update your post with sample data. You can create a dataframe from a dictionary.

Comment: always put code, data and error message as text, not image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create function which does what you need and use `df.apply()` to execute it on all rows.

I use example data from @Boomer answer.

**EDIT:** you didn't show what you really have in dataframe and it seems you have `datetime` in `bill_date` but I used strings. I had to convert strings to `datetime` to show how to work with this. And now it needs `.strftime('%m-%y')` or sometimes `.dt.strftime('%m-%y')` instead of `.str[3:].str.replace('/','-')`. Because pandas uses different formats to display dateitm for different countries so I couldn't use `str(x)` for this because it gives me `2019-09-15 00:00:00` instead of yours `15/09/19`

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'bill_number': ['CM2/0000/', 'CM2/0000', 'CM3/0000/', 'CM3/0000'],
    'bill_date': ['15/09/19', '15/09/19', '15/09/19', '15/09/19']
})
df['bill_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['bill_date'])

def convert(row):
    if row['bill_number'].endswith('/'):
        #return row['bill_number'] + row['bill_date'].str[3:].replace('/','-')
        return row['bill_number'] + row['bill_date'].strftime('%m-%y')
    else:
        return row['bill_number']

df['bill_number'] = df.apply(convert, axis=1)

print(df)
```

Result:

```
      bill_number bill_date
0  CM2/0000/09-19  15/09/19
1        CM2/0000  15/09/19
2  CM3/0000/09-19  15/09/19
3        CM3/0000  15/09/19
```

---

Second idea is to create mask

```
 mask = df['bill_number'].str.endswith('/')
```

and later use it for all values

```
 #df.loc[mask,'bill_number'] = df[mask]['bill_number'] + df[mask]['bill_date'].str[3:].str.replace('/','-')
 df.loc[mask,'bill_number'] = df[mask]['bill_number'] + df[mask]['bill_date'].dt.strftime('%m-%y')
```

or

```
 #df.loc[mask,'bill_number'] = df.loc[mask,'bill_number'] + df.loc[mask,'bill_date'].str[3:].str.replace('/','-')
 df.loc[mask,'bill_number'] = df.loc[mask,'bill_number'] + df.loc[mask,'bill_date'].dt.strftime('%m-%y')
```

Left side needs `.loc[mask,'bill_number']` instead of `[mask]['bill_number'] to correctly assing values - but right side doesn't need it.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'bill_number': ['CM2/0000/', 'CM2/0000', 'CM3/0000/', 'CM3/0000'],
    'bill_date': ['15/09/19', '15/09/19', '15/09/19', '15/09/19']
})
df['bill_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['bill_date'])

mask = df['bill_number'].str.endswith('/')

#df.loc[mask,'bill_number'] = df[mask]['bill_number'] + df[mask]['bill_date'].str[3:].str.replace('/','-')
# or
#df.loc[mask,'bill_number'] = df.loc[mask,'bill_number'] + df.loc[mask,'bill_date'].str[3:].str.replace('/','-')

df.loc[mask,'bill_number'] = df[mask]['bill_number'] + df[mask]['bill_date'].dt.strftime('%m-%y')
#or
#df.loc[mask,'bill_number'] = df.loc[mask,'bill_number'] + df.loc[mask,'bill_date'].dt.strftime('%m-%y')

print(df)
```

---

Third idea is to use `numpy.where()`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'bill_number': ['CM2/0000/', 'CM2/0000', 'CM3/0000/', 'CM3/0000'],
    'bill_date': ['15/09/19', '15/09/19', '15/09/19', '15/09/19']
})
df['bill_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['bill_date'])

df['bill_number'] = np.where(
                       df['bill_number'].str.endswith('/'), 
                       #df['bill_number'] + df['bill_date'].str[3:].str.replace('/','-'), 
                       df['bill_number'] + df['bill_date'].dt.strftime('%m-%y'), 
                       df['bill_number'])

print(df)
```

Comment: I tried two of these answers, the def (row) one gave me this error: TypeError: ("'Timestamp' object is not subscriptable", 'occurred at index 0') and i tried the np.where approach which gave me this error:  AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas

Comment: problem is that you didn't show real data in your question. Error shows that  you have `timestamp` in column `bill_date` but I have only strings. I have to convert my strings to `datetime` to test code - it seems you need `row['bill_date'].strftime('%m-%y')` instead of `df['bill_date'].str[3:].str.replace('/','-')`

Comment: I changed examples in answer. Now it uses `datetime` instead of strings

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will work for you. It would be nice to have a data sample like @Mike67 was stating. But based on your information this is what I came up with. Bulky, but it works. I'm sure someone else will have a fancier version.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame, Series

dat = {'num': ['CM2/0000/','CM2/0000', 'CM3/0000/', 'CM3/0000',],
    'date': ['15/09/19','15/09/19','15/09/19','15/09/19']}
df = pd.DataFrame(dat)

df['date'] = df['date'].map(lambda x: str(x)[3:])
df['date'] = df['date'].str.replace('/','-')

for cols in df.columns:
df.loc[df['num'].str.endswith('/'), cols] = df['num'] + df['date']

print(df)

Results:
              num   date
0  CM2/0000/09-19  09-19
1        CM2/0000  09-19
2  CM3/0000/09-19  09-19
3        CM3/0000  09-19
```